# Prove that every non-trivial representation of a simple finite group is isomorphic to the group itself

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

If $G$ is a simple group then the only subgroups are $\{E\},G$.

I have a feeling I need to use the cosets of the normal subgroup $\{E\}$ and construct an isomorphism between them and the representation matrices. Why? Because I know that there are $|G|$ cosets of $\{E\}$ and that these cosets are just $\{g_i\}$, where $g_i$ are the elements of $G$.

I'm not sure how to link all of this to a non-trivial representation, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $\rho\colon  G\rightarrow GL_n(K)$ is a linear representation. Then $\ker(\rho)$ is a normal subgroup of $G$. Since $G$ is simple, either $\rho=0$, or $\ker(\rho)=0$. The latter says that $\rho$ is faithful, i.e., $G\cong \rho(G)$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: a representation is a group homomorphism (of a special kind). Now, the kernel of **any** group homomorphism is a *normal* subgroup, so...